# How to inherits differents models in the same view in ASP MVC

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3

I am developing an ASP .Net MVC 3 application using C# and SQL Server 2005.

I am using also Entity Framework and Code First Method.

I have a partial View 'Gestion.ascx' which contains a Form (textbox and listbox).

This view use a ViewModel 'FlowViewModel'.

I want that this the view use another model 'Gamme' which i already have.

I try it to put them both in the 'inherits markup' **but some statements became underlined in RED.**

***Infact, to explain more the question :***

I used the FlowViewModel in this partial view in order to load some data in my list boxfrom differents models.

Now I want to store values selected and entred in a local variables.

**I can't pass from the model 'Gamme' to the controller because the view 'Gestion' is not using the model 'Gamme'.**

This is the code of the partial view 'Gestion' :

```
<%@  Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<MvcApplication2.Models.FlowViewModel>" %>

<% using (Html.BeginForm("Save", "Anouar")) { %>
    <%: Html.ValidationSummary(true) %>
    <fieldset class="parametrage">
        <legend>Gestion de Gamme</legend>

        <div><%:Html.Label("Poste :")%><%: Html.DropDownList("SelectedPoste", Model.PostesItems)%><input type="checkbox" name="option1" value="Poste Initial" id= "chkMain" onclick="test();"/>Poste Initial<input type="checkbox" name="option2" value="Poste Final" id= "chkFirst" onclick="test2();"/>Poste Final</div>


         <div><%:Html.Label("Nombre de Passage :")%><%: Html.EditorFor(x=>x.YourGammeModel.Nbr_Passage)%></div>
        <div><%:Html.Label("Position :")%><%: Html.EditorFor(x=>x.YourGammeModel.Position)%></div>
        <div><%:Html.Label("Poste Précédent :")%><%: Html.DropDownList("PostePrecedentSelected", Model.PostesItems)%></div>
        <div><%:Html.Label("Poste Suivant :")%><%: Html.DropDownList("PosteSuivantSelected", Model.PostesItems)%></div>


        <div><input type="submit" value="Enregistrer" id="btnSave"  /></div>

        </fieldset>
<% } %>
```

and this is the code of the model 'FlowViewModel' :

```
namespace MvcApplication2.Models
{
    public class FlowViewModel
    {

        [Key]
        public string IDv { get; set; }
        [NotMapped]
        public SelectList PostesItems { get; set; }

        public List<Profile_Ga> Profile_GaItems { get; set; }
        public List<Gamme> GaItems { get; set; }

        public Gamme YourGammeModel { get; set; }

        public int SelectedProfile_Ga { get; set; }

        public int SelectedGamme{ get; set; }

        public int SelectedPoste { get; set; }

        public int PostePrecedentSelected { get; set; } 
        public int PosteSuivantSelected { get; set; }
}
}
```

and this is the model 'Gamme' :

```
public class Gamme
    {
        [Key]
        [Column(Order = 0)]
        [ForeignKey("Profile_Ga")]
        public string ID_Gamme { get; set; }
        [Key]
        [Column(Order = 1)]
        [ForeignKey("Poste")]
        public string ID_Poste { get; set; }
        public int Position { get; set; }
        public int Nbr_Passage { get; set; }
        public string Last_Posts { get; set; }
        public string Next_Posts { get; set; }

        public virtual Poste Poste { get; set; }
        public virtual Profile_Ga Profile_Ga { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see anything in common between the view models Gamme and FlowViewModel. In that case, it would be incorrect to use the same view. If they have something in common extract that to a base view model and write the view for that base view model, rather than retro fit.

Comment: @Sruti thx,,but that's anothor complicated issue,,experts here who advice to use that to solve another problem,,,so let's forget it,,,but is there solution to use them both in the view?

Answer (score 1):

Replace this "<%: Html.EditorFor(x=>x.YourGammeModel.Nbr_Passage)%>" code with 
"<%: Html.Textbox("Nbr_Passage",(Model != null && Model.YourGammeModel != null) ? Model.YourGammeModel.Nbr_Passage : 0) %>"

And in Post method you include 
for example

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Save (FlowViewModel flowViewModel, FromCollection form)
{
//get value using formcollection
int Nbr_Passage = (int)form["Nbr_Passage"];

}
```